# Does npx look for globally installed packages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npx

I am using Node.js 10.1.0 and npm 6.0.0.

I have installed a package with `npm install -g example-package`,

Will `npx` look for it? What about `npx -p example-package`, does it only look on npm registry?

Comment: npx looks in local /node_modules folder for the example-package and if it is not available , it downloads and runs but it doesnt look for global , as it is kind of replacement for global

Comment: chekc this link for more details - https://blog.scottlogic.com/2018/04/05/npx-the-npm-package-runner.html

Comment: The benefit of `npx` is that you don't need to use `-g` anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NPX included in NPM 5.2 which looks in your local/node_modules folder to avoid version mismatch with the globally installed package version

If package is not available, npx will automatically install npm packages and it will not be looking for globally installed packages

Check this link for reference - https://blog.scottlogic.com/2018/04/05/npx-the-npm-package-runner.html

Comment: @bluelovers is saying that it look into global.

Comment: Your answer is unclear, @bluelovers is right. check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx

"By default, npx will check whether <command> exists in $PATH, or in the local project binaries, and execute that. If <command> is not found, it will be installed prior to execution"

Comment: @red , not sure what is unclear, i gave same information with reference link, did you check that link?..and not sure for downvote

Comment: where does `npx` install the package? does it install at global scope or local to the project?

Comment: Note: When npx installs the package, I found that it just installs it in the npm cache and runs it from there. It does not install it locally nor globally.

Answer (score 11):

In `Node.js v10` (`npm@6` and probably later);

`npx` will look global binaries, after looking locally.

But we can use `-p` option to prevent looking globally, like:

```
npx -p name_of_module
```

> **Note** `npx` is an `npm` package runner that executes a `<command>` (e.g. npm package binaries) by FIRST looking in local `node_modules/.bin` directory.
>
> So even if we remove it from `package.json`, as long as binary exists in `node_modules/.bin`, `npx` will continue using local.

Comment: This should be the right answer. If the package is available locally it will take it, otherwise it falls back to the global one.

Comment: Not sure this is still working: `npx -p jest --version` gives me 6.14.15 which is my current npm version, not jest version. `npx jest --version` gives me 27.3.1 which is accurate.

Comment: @jcollum When using the `-p` opton we need to follow this format: `npx [options] [-p|--package <package>]... <command> [command-arg]...`. So, it looks like `npx -p jest jest --version` will do the right thing. I guess this is to support packages where the command name is not the same as the package name (e.g. `typescript` package has `tsc` as main command)